# Equality in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Im performing some operations in a df of 4000 columns and 17520 rows. I have to repeat these operations 100 times with 5 different randomly selected columns from the df. I am using the following function:

```
    for i in range(0,100):
    rand_cols = np.random.permutation(df.columns)[0:5]
    df2 = df[rand_cols]
    df2[:,:] *= 2
```

My question is the following:

Does the operation in the df2 which is the 5 random columns of df affect the columns in the original df?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? You can build a smaller test dataframe, use yoru code, and check by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't. Just like Valentino in the comments suggested, if you try it with some dummy DataFrame, you can see it doesn't change:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'c':range(50)})
df2=df.loc[df['c']%2==0,:]
df2*=10
```

if you look at df you can see it didn't change.

The reason is df2 saves the view of df but not the data itself